# Query datetime in SQL without time

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, datetime

I'm trying to write a SQL query which should just pick the count with specific date not time.

```
select count(*) from xyz where time='2010-01-21'
```

but it is not returning any results.

Comment: What is the field type of the time column?

Comment: datetime is the datatype

Comment: sql server 2008 management studio

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have a date time field, and you wanted to match a date:

`select count(*) from xyz where time BETWEEN '2010-01-21' AND '2010-01-22`'

## [MYSQL Date Time ref](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/datetime.html)

Answer (score 7):

For SQL Server 2008, you should be able to use the [date](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb630352(v=SQL.100).aspx) data type:

```
select count(*) from xyz where cast(time as date) = '2010-01-21'
```

Comment: +1 I originally commented that this is non sargable and can't use an index [But this connect request](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/526431/make-more-functions-sargable) says that it **is in fact** sargable (news to me!).

Answer (score 1):

Try (MySQL)

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM xyz WHERE DATE(datetime_col) = '2010-01-21'
```

in T-SQL (MSSQL) (kinda ugly, but should work):

```
SELECT * FROM xyz WHERE CAST(CONVERT(varchar(8), datetime_col, 112) AS DATETIME) <= '2011-01-21'
```

Comment: I assume the OP is on sql-server but just messed up the tags.

Comment: Im gettihg this error:'Date' is not a recognized built-in function name.